# A cloth mat spread

Tags: vocabulary

[image]

The thing we see in the picture is especially used in S. Asia. It is called DARRI there. They usually use this in gatherings for sitting arrangements on the floor. What is the particular word for this in UK, USA, South Africa and Canada? Would you call it:

1. Cloth mat
2. Rug
3. Fabric floor covering
4. Woven mat

Answer (score 1):

It appears in English dictionaries as "dhurrie", and is defined variously as a flat-woven rug or carpet.
[onelook.com "dhurrie"](https://onelook.com/?w=dhurrie&ssbp=1&ls=a)
That will get multiple definitions in English.

There's also a Wikipedia article:
[Wikipedia "dhurrie"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhurrie)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be specfic "a cloth mat from south Asia for sitting on" you call it a "darri" or [dhurrie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhurrie), and accept that for most native speakers you will also need to describe it.

If you don't need to be specfic you call it a *mat* or a *rug* (both are possible)

Everything else is a description.  You could describe it as "cloth" or "woven" or "pattern" or "colourful" or "South Asian". It depends on what you want to tell the other person about it.

> I'll get my mother in law a darri for her birthday.
>
> What's that?
>
> Its a kind of colourful woven rug for sitting on.